# mongoose user bulk search by phone numbers

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have UserSchema which contains PhoneNumberSchema as below.

```
var PhoneNumberSchema = new Schema({
    country: {
        type: String
    },
    country_code: {
        type: Number
    },
    local_number: {
        type: Number
    }
});
```

And here is sample json format of phone_number.

```
"phone_number": {
    "country": "US",
    "country_code": "1",
    "local_number": "04152341"
}
```

What I want to do is to search users by phone numbers with / without country code.

Well, if request is

> "phone_numbers": [    "104152341",    "124254364" ]

then I want to get users who has exactly matched phone number which belongs in the request phone numbers array with/without country code.

So, I tried as below, but got error "invalid operator '$in'".

```
User.aggregate(
    [   
        { "$redact": { 
            "$cond": [ 
                { 
                    "$in": [ { "$concat": [ "$phone_number.country_code", "$phone_number.local_number" ] }, req.body.phone_numbers]
                },
                "$$KEEP",
                "$$PRUNE"
            ]
        }}
    ],
    function(err, users) {
        // Do something
        if (err) {
            return res.json({ success: false, err: err });
        }
        res.json({ success: true, users: users });
    }
)
```

I hope to know how to handle my issue.

Please help me !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **[`$setIsSubset`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setIsSubset/#exp._S_setIsSubset)** as your condition expression:

```
{ "$redact": { 
    "$cond": [ 
        { 
            "$setIsSubset": [ 
                [ 
                    { 
                        "$concat": [ 
                            "$phone_number.country_code", 
                            "$phone_number.local_number" 
                        ] 
                    } 
                ], 
                req.body.phone_numbers 
            ]
        },
        "$$KEEP",
        "$$PRUNE"
    ]
}}
```

Comment: Excellent, though we need also handle with/without country code, $setIsSubset is good for two fields concatenation. :)